# How to overwrite a preallocated char array in C

Tags: c

I initialize a `char` array as a global variable in my C program with a default file location/name as

```
char file[] = "/home/jack/files/data.txt";
```

Later in the program, if a condition is satisfied I read a file containing a new file name

```
int read_new_file(char *fname)
{
    FILE *inp;
    char buffer[255];
    char oldFile[127], newFile[127];

    inp = fopen(fname, "r");
    while ( fgets(buffer, 255, inp) != NULL )
    {
         sscanf(buffer, "%s %s",oldFile,newFile);

         file = newFile; // <---- Is this wrong/unsafe?

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I should note that it is assumed file `fname` only contains one line with 2 strings. This was just to show the general framework of the code. My question, as highlighted in the code, is it wrong or unsafe to simply try and reassign the `char file` variable with the new string?

The size of the `newFile` string will likely differ from it's original default size. The default has to be predefined, since the condition may not require a new file to be read. If the assignment is wrong or unsafe, what is a better approach?

Comment: The "wrong" part should be obvious; it doesn't *compile*, so yeah, it's wrong.

Comment: Doesn't your C tutorial teach about `strcpy()`?

Comment: @Barmar It just did ; )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `file` so it's large enough to hold `newFile`.

```
char file[127] = "/home/jack/files/data.txt";
```

Then when you want to update it, you use:

```
strcpy(file, newFile);
```

Comment: You'd also want to restrict the `scanf` (or increase the `oldFile`/`newFile` sizes) so it can't overflow `oldFile` and `newFile`; right now, `oldFile` `scanf` could read the full 255  characters into `oldFile` and simply fail to fill in `newFile` at all (check `sscanf`'s return value to notice this), or even if it parses both with no `fgets` truncation involved, it could parse 200 into `oldFile` and 40 into `newFile`.

Comment: I'm going to let that go, and assume that he knows the format of the input file a priori, and it's 2 filenames that are up to 126 bytes each.

Answer (score 1):

```
file = newFile; // <---- Is this wrong/unsafe?
```

It is wrong since `file` is an array. The compiler won't let you do that.
Whether it is safe or not is not relevant since you can't do it.

Use `strcpy` instead.

```
strcpy(file, newFile);
```

Comment: You can't even perform the assignment, since `file` is an array, not a pointer.